# File is not downloading blob when link.click is called in IE

Tags: events, hyperlink, download, click, blob

I am trying to download some blob by creating a link in clicking it at runtime. 
This works fine in chrome and FF but nothing downloads in IE11.

```
var blob = new Blob([], { type: 'text/csv' });

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'Test.csv';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Try open http://jsfiddle.net/rq8460cL/3/ in chrome/FF and it will download file but IE nothing happens. 
Any Help please???

Comment: The download attribute isn't supported in IE.

Comment: @Musa, Thanks for info. Is there any way I can achieve this for IE?

Comment: IE10+ has  msSaveBlob and msSaveOrOpenBlob